# How to compute Total Price in Java Ordering System?

Tags: java

I'm just a first year College Student and my project is creating an Ordering System but i'm stuck on the pricing because i can't do the total price right. When the program loops it calculated the price wrong . A1 and A2 is the only choice i enter because this is still an unfinished project.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Ordering_System
{
     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
     {
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String order,again;
         int quantity,price1=0,price2=0,loop1=0,quantity1,quantity2=0;

         System.out.println("  ");  

         System.out.println("Welcome to MgRonalds, What do you want to order?");

         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("*******************************************************************");
         System.out.println("*   Code    Meal             ''MENU''              Price          *");
         System.out.println("*                                                                 *");
         System.out.println("*   (A1)   MgBurger                                P30.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (A2)   Big Mac                                 P139.00        *");
         System.out.println("*   (B1)   Cheese Burger                           P35.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (B2)   Chicken Burger                          P50.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (C1)   MgNuggets                               P65.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (C2)   MgChicken                               P79.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (D1)   MgSpagetti                              P60.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (D2)   MgFries                                 P40.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (E1)   Coke                                    P10.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (E2)   Sprite                                  P10.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (E3)   Royal                                   P10.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (F1)   Sundae                                  P25.00         *");
         System.out.println("*   (F2)   MgFloat                                 P25.00         *");
         System.out.println("*                                                                 *");
         System.out.println("*******************************************************************");

         do{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Enter Code Order      : ");
            order=br.readLine();
            if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A1")) {
                price1=30;
                System.out.println("Order Description     : MgBurger ");
            } else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A2")) {
                price1=139;
                System.out.println("Order Description     : Big Mac ");
            }   

            System.out.print("Enter Quantity        : ");
            quantity1= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            quantity2=quantity1+quantity2;

            price2=price1*quantity2;   

            System.out.print("Another Order?  (Y/N) : ");
            again=br.readLine();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                loop1=loop1+1;
            else loop1=loop1-100;
      } while (loop1==1);    

     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.println("Total Price           : "+price2);   

 }
}
```

Here's an example output:

```
Enter Code Order      : a1
Order Description     : MgBurger 
Enter Quantity        : 2
Another Order?  (Y/N) : y

Enter Code Order      : a2
Order Description     : Big Mac 
Enter Quantity        : 2
Another Order?  (Y/N) : n

Total Price           : 556
```

The answer should be 338 not 556

Comment: I recommend stepping through your code in a debugger and watching what the values are during execution of your code. I bet you'll find where you're calculating things based on the wrong values pretty quickly :)  Also, it'll help if you give your variables more descriptive names, like `totalPrice` and `priceForCurrentItem`, etc, which will make it even more clear when you're using your variables in the wrong place.

Comment: I never knew that `McDonalds` had a new franchise called `MgRonalds`! :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you simply do this?
Add a variable `total =0;`

```
  System.out.print("Enter Quantity        : ");
  quantity1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  // quantity2=quantity1+quantity2;

  // price2=price1*quantity2;

  total += price1 * quantity1;

  ...
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Total Price           : " + total);
```

Comment: Thank You!! You really helped me with this one. This is my problem since yesteday..

Answer (score 1):

Let's work this out logically:

On **first** loop:

> Enter Code Order      : a1

Now,`price1 = 30`

Order Description     : MgBurger

> Enter Quantity        : 2

```
quantity1 = 2
quantity2 = quantity1 + quantity2 = 2 + 0 = 2;
price2 = 30 * 2 = 60;
```

Agreed?

> Another Order?  (Y/N) : y

On **second loop**, we still have `price1=30`, `quantity1 = 2`, `quantity2 = 2` and `price2 = 60`. Now:

> Enter Code Order      : a2

```
price1 = 139
```

> Order Description     : Big Mac
>
> Enter Quantity        : 2

```
quantity1 = 2;
quantity2 = quantity1 + quantity2 = 2 + 2 = 4;
price2 = 139 * 4 = 556;
```

Found the mistake yet? `quantity2` still retains the value of the previous transaction in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can really simplify you code as follows. Also consider using a float value for the price instead of int.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("  ");

  // Display the Menu

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String order, again;
  int quantity = 0;
  int total = 0;
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter Code Order      : ");
    order = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Quantity        : ");
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    total += getPrice(order) * quantity;

    System.out.print("Another Order?  (Y/N) : ");
    again = br.readLine();
    if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
      break;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Total Price           : " + total);
}

private static int getPrice(String order) {
  int price = 0;
  // using switch-case would be more appropriate
  if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A1")) {
    price = 30;
    System.out.println("Order Description     : MgBurger ");
  } else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A2")) {
    price = 139;
    System.out.println("Order Description     : Big Mac ");
  }
  return price;
}
```